# How to create a backlink in my youtube channel/video pages to promote my website?

Tags: seo, backlinks, youtube

I want to use my YouTube channel and video pages to promote my website.

I have read a website that talks about backlinks and anchors which use something like: `<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>` to create the backlink . 
However as I know I cannot create a backlink like that in video description. How I can create a backlink for my website in YouTube?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, you can't, except you have a brand or partner channel, which allows you to do that. Place a link in the description of your video instead and make sure it's above the fold if your video description is longer:

[image: Youtube Video Description]